# Is it possible to generate atom-mapped xyz files from reaction SMILES for NEB?

Tags: geometry, transition-state, smiles, nudged-elastic-band

There are SMILES that represent reactions happening (e.g. `C=C.O>>CCO` representing water addition to ethylene). And I know that there are atom-mapping softwares available from molecule sketchers (ChemAxon, ChemDraw) and also from neural networks (rxnmapper published by Schwaller). However, these mappers seem to work only by mapping the SMILES (i.e. 2D connectivity)

**Is there a mapping algorithm, or a way to generate properly atom-mapped 3D geometries (xyz) from SMILES for both reactants and products that can be used e.g. to start an NEB calculation?** In NEB for instance the ordering of atoms is very important, so if the mapping is not right, then the calculation will run into issues. It is easy to imagine a scenario where 2D mapping is correct but 3D mapping isn't: a benzene ring attached to a functional group can have two orientations (due to the local symmetry of the ring). If the orientation is not the same in reactant and product then NEB will consider the rotation of the ring as part of the reaction. (It also applies to other double-ended TS search methods like pyGSM).

Comment: I am looking for existing algorithms, papers, software etc.

Comment: I'm surprised that I was the only one that upvoted.

Comment: @NikeDattani Maybe 3D mapping reactions is not a problem that comes up often